# I want to play htmlDecode after JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

I want to parse string having quotes in value into JSON.

After the string of JSON.stringify() is htmlDecode(), the quot; is converted to " and an error occurs when JSON.parse().

new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html"); during the process 
Can it be executed except "quot;"

Or is there another way?

```
  <script>
    const str = "&lt ;h3&gt ;&amp ;&amp ;&amp ;&quot ;&quot ;xx;;&lt ;/h3&gt ; &lt ;h2&gt ;";
    const obj = { "test1": "&lt ;h3&gt ;&amp ;&amp ;&amp ;&quot ;&quot ;xx;;&l t;/h3&gt ; &lt ;h2&gt ; ", "test2": "help" };

    function htmlDecode(input) {
      var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
      return doc.documentElement.textContent;
    }

    console.log(htmlDecode(str))    // <h3>&&&""xx;;</h3> <h2>
    console.log(htmlDecode(JSON.stringify(obj)))  // {"test1":"<h3>&&&""xx;;</h3> <h2> ","test2":"help"}
    console.log(JSON.parse(htmlDecode(JSON.stringify(obj)))) // VM49:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 18 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
  </script>
</body>
```

If string does not include qout; JSON Parsing is wokring well.

```
const quotIsNotObj = { "test1": "&lt ;h3&gt ;&amp ;&amp ;&amp ;xx;;&lt ;/h3&gt ; &lt ;h2&gt ; ", "test2": "help" };

console.log(JSON.parse(htmlDecode(JSON.stringify(successObj)))) // {"test1":"<h3>&&&xx;;</h3> <h2> ","test2":"help"}
```

Comment: JSON is nothing to do with HTML - what you are doing makes no sense at all, you can't "parse" HTML as JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX I want to decodeHtml all the string in json at once. If the value is not qout; it is parsed well.

Comment: Oh, right, so the `textContent` isn't proper JSON - sorry, I didn't read the full code in `htmlDecode` (assumed you were returning html, my bad) - yeah ... that's a problem alright

Comment: 1) Are the spaces in your JSON a formatting error? The way they're presented here, they won't get output like that.
2) Do you want to end up with a JS object or HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Escape String Included in object. And That will parse Into JSON.

```js
const str = "&lt;h3&gt;&amp;&amp;&amp;&quot;&quot;xx;;&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;h2&gt;";
const obj = { 'test1': '&lt;h3&gt;&amp;&amp;&amp;&quot;&quot;xx;;&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;h2&gt; ', 'test2': 'help'};


console.log(htmlDecode(str))    // <h3>&&&""xx;;</h3> <h2>
console.log(htmlDecode(JSON.stringify(obj)))  // {"test1":"<h3>&&&""xx;;</h3> <h2> ","test2":"help"}

//Creating New Object With Escaped String
 var newObj={};
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
   var newVal=escapeString(htmlDecode(obj[key]));
    newObj[key]=newVal;
 });
 console.log(newObj);
   
   
 
function htmlDecode(input) {
      var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
      return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

//To Escape Characters like Quote
 function escapeString(jsonStr){
  return jsonStr.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")
                .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
                .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
                .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
                .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
                .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
                .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
                .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Except for everything else.

Is it possible to have a single .replace (/\\"/g, '\ \ ") problem?                   　　　　　　　        
Example of viewing and applying answers : 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　function htmlDecode(input) {
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　      var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
     　　　　　　　　　　　　 doc = doc.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"')　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
      return doc.documentElement.textContent;
    }

Comment: that would not appropriate way.

Comment: function decodeHtmlInJson(json) {
 return JSON.parse(new DOMParser().parseFromString(JSON.stringify(json).replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"'), "text/html")
    .documentElement.textContent);
}　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Why isn't it appropriate to use this for a project?

Comment: this would be static for quote only. what if string will include other special characters??

Comment: After changing everything special in the (new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html")),
Isn't it just qout; that are problematic when you do JSON.parse()?

Comment: no. there is more. like backslash, tab, new line and more.

Comment: Just json.parse() doesn't it matter if you like backslash, tab, new line?  　　　　　　　　　　 　　　　　　　　Is there an example of a problem?

Comment: I understand perfectly. Thank you.